# Expanding available space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I have three disks in my setup. On one of them I have windows (250GB), one is for Games (1TB) and on the third one is my Ubuntu System (126GB). My Ubuntu disk is divided in 2 (or three?) partitions. There is partition 2 which holds partition 5 and  67GB of free space. Partition 5 has the OS and installed software on it (currently 73,8% full). The 67GB of free space are currently not usable.

I could of course mount them. In that case, the freshly created partition shows up in the explorer under "Other Locations". But that's not what I want, because installed software will always end up on partition 5. So, how can I add the free space to partition 5?

[image]

I tried a lot of different things, like trying to "merge" with GParted or trying with `resize2fs`. The terminology is very confusing to me, but I still feel like it should be easy to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use partdisk in windows if you cannot get a live disk. I forgot about the fact that you have the partition loaded.

Comment: What I did was to use gparted from a USB. You may have to change boot priority. Then I were able to resize my partition without losing data.